# If-else condition in loop: future iterations overwrite results of previous iterations

Tags: c++, qt

I try to highlight a `selectedItem` and its *children* among a list of `items`.

```cpp
const QList<Item *> items = /* ... */;
Item *selectedItem = /* ... */;

Q_FOREACH( Item *item, items ) {
    if ( selectedItem == item ) {
        item->setHighlightEnabled(true); // Highlight selected item
    } else {
        item->setHighlightEnabled(false); // De-highlight other items
    }
}
```

The `item->setHighlightEnabled` method does the same for children recursively:

```cpp
void Item::setHighlightEnabled(bool enabled)
{
    if (enabled) {
        /* highlight item */
    } else {
        /* de-highlight item */
    }

    // Go through all children and highlight them too
    Q_FOREACH (Item *child, children())
        child->setHighlightEnabled(enabled);    

}
```

---

Works fine but there is a bug. We loop over **all** items. When a parent is selected, parent and its children are highlighted. But then loop continues iterating over children. Since children are NOT selected, therefore they are de-highlighted (overwriting highlight in previous loop iterations). I wonder what is the best practice to fix it.

Comment: What if you check the highlight status before changing it?

Comment: when I read this I've got feeling that some problem introduction is missing. I like straight to the point, but without skipping vital information. What is the `Item` is it your implementation of data model? Is it selection model? What widget do you use? Did you set its properties properly?

Comment: @vahancho Assume an item X is previously selected (highlighted) by the user, then user clicks on item Y. The item Y (and its children) need to be highlighted and item X need to be de-highlighted. Therefore, highlight status isn't a reliable thing to check

Comment: I'm suspecting [this is a problem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum).

Comment: @user3405291, if `y1` is a child of `Y`, check whether is's highlighted before changing its status to avoid toggling the status.

Comment: Nitpick: I *really hate* `if (children().size()) Q_FOREACH ...`. Unconditionally looping does the *same thing*

Comment: Is `selectedItem` not one of the pointers in `items`? Are there multiple "items" with the same name?

Comment: @molbdnilo We have name checking to make sure there are no duplicate names. But you're right, maybe it is good enough to just compare pointers (rather than comparing names)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De-highlight everything first, then highlight the current selection.

If `selectedItem` already is a pointer to the only element you want to highlight, you don't need to search for it, you only need:

```
Q_FOREACH (Item *item, items)
    item->setHighlightEnabled(false);
selectedItem->setHighlightEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as i understand your problem, you could make to for-loops. In the first one you de-highlight all elements. And the second one you leve as is and just stop it with a `break;` statement, once it found the selected item.